# Css : creating cornered border using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-shapes

I've to create something  you see in attached image

[image]

right now i am using this as background image

```
background-image: url("corner.png");
background-size: cover;
```

and then added text but i know there  does exist a css solution for creating this border for this so if someone please help me with this i tried to find but i did not find proper solution

Comment: There are a couple websites where you can create them visually by fiddling with a few knobs. Search for something like *css border arrow* or *css border triangle* and you should find them.

Comment: Duplicate solved my problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also generate it from the below link and use it.

http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

```css
.arrow {
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  background: #333;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #333;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: Answers should not just be links to an external site and they should be able to stand on their own (just in-case the linked site goes down). Please add atleast the generated code to your answer.

Comment: ok Harry Next time i will take care of that thing :)

Comment: That's fine but unless you update this answer it could be deleted by the reviewers (community) and you'd stand to lose any rep gained because of it. So, better take care of it this time itself :)

Comment: You have 2 up votes for the answer but also been flagged as low quality post. It is better you update the answer with relevant code for avoiding deletion.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.arrow-down {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
.arrow-down:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -19px;
}
```

```html
<div class='arrow-down'>fgdfgdfgfd</div>
```

This will help you.
it will create arrows using css.

> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: An appreciable answer! Please add your comments as well if 'This answer in not useful'.

Comment: @KunJ: I wasn't the one to downvote but the initial version of this answer was a link only version which might have prompted the downvote (and I can't justify why the other link only answer didn't get any too).

Comment: Yes may be that's why i have added code for more detail,

Comment: And if that's the reason then why @kushalkant have up voted :(

Comment: @Harry , thanks for reply and contribution! Right said. Down voter should alter his/her vote if mitul improved his answer :)

Comment: @all may be stackoverflow send notification to down voter if user change the ans so he/she review the new ans and change the vote. right now if some one give down vote and leave the page then he can not see if the user change the ans.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uwred6y/) Hope you refer something like this.

```
a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  width:140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a.tooltips span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.8;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -76px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fiddle , but thats not a tooltip acutally , its div itself .